Chrome extension service worker inject script to new about:blank tab
I am writing an extension to create a new tab then run some script. However, the error message "Error: Cannot access "about:blank" at origin "null". Extension must have permission to access the frame's origin, and matchAboutBlank must be true." always comes out.
The following is my code in the service worker (Manifest v3):
let openedTab = await chrome.tabs.create({active: false, openerTabId: sender.tab.id, url: "about:blank"});
openedTabID = openedTab.id;
                    
let writeHTML = function (strHTML) {
    console.log("injected");
}
chrome.scripting.executeScript({target : {tabId : openedTabID, allFrames : true}, func : writeHTML});

Before using the chrome.tabs.create method to open new tab, I used the simple window.open() to open an about:blank page and by capturing the new opened tab id using chrome.webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget.addListener, I can use the same chrome.scripting.executeScript({target : {tabId : openedTabID}, func : writeHTML}); and it worked smoothly. However, I want to open a blurred (inactive) tab, but window.open always open the tab focused, and even a later window.blur() not working smoothly. So I changed using the tabs.create, but unfortunately the situation seems a bit complicated.
I searched online, such as adding allFrames : true or matchAboutBlank: true, but have no luck. Some solutions online are also for manifest v2, such as using tabs.executeScript, instead of scripting.executeScript. Hopefully I can get a solution here. Thanks!
Expecting a code, as simple as possible, to inject a script to about:blank page.

In Chrome executeScript can't inject into about:blank tabs, only in about:blank frames. Try to create it using any valid web URL, then call stop() inside the code injected via executeScript with injectImmediately:true. Why do you need to create a new tab? There may a better solution.

The plan is to create a new tab and write some html based on the mother page's content then print the new tab to PDF.

Any reference that executeScript can't inject to about:blank? That quite surprise me, as the original older version tabs.executeScript can inject. And why can I inject a script if the tab is created by window.open()? It's also about:blank pagr

So what u mean is to put a random URL, and stop asap by calling immediately true? And after that i can clear all HTML loaded and write my own HTML?


It just can't in MV3, dunno about MV2. Try reporting in https://crbug.com. See also this comment. 2) As for window.open, it preserves the internal "origin" of the page, which is used for injection. 3) Yes. You can use stop(); document.write('new html') to overwrite it.


It seems like I can't document.write(...) after I stop() the page. The page just not responding to my change. Any idea why? Or you can answer in my another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78474540/unable-to-document-write-after-stop
