Unable to document.write after stop()
I'm writing a Chrome extension, which creates a new tab then inject a script to overwrite the whole HTML of it. (a bit of the background can refer to another post: Chrome extension service worker inject script to new about:blank tab). Here is the script:
let openedTab = await chrome.tabs.create({active: false, url: randomURL});

openedTabID = openedTab.id;
                    
let writeHTML = function (strHTML) {
    stop();
    //document.open();
    document.write(strHTML)
    //document.close();
}
chrome.scripting.executeScript({target : {tabId : openedTabID}, func : writeHTML, injectImmediately: true, args: [newTabHTML[0].result]});

I find that the strHTML cannot be written to it sucessfully, the page keeps in blank (blank due to loading stopped), unless I don't stop() the loading of the page. If I don't stop() it, the strHTML can overwrite the page, but just the tab icon keeps circling around (loading). I find that quite annoying and I afraid that the original page (the url: randomURL) will eventually be loaded and affect my intended actions afterwards. So I want to ask how I can trully stop the loading of the page before I write my HTML to it?
Here is some troubleshooting I tried......
I tried to manually put document.write("asdasd") into the console, no observed change but only return undefined but no error too.
I tried to manually enter asdasadasdsd between the loaded html tag, also no observed change. Seems like the display is not linked with the html code if I stop() the page.
I'm not very sure whether this is due to the original page is an angularJS page, as if I stop() the loading immediately I inject the script, the HTML loaded is
<html ng-app="ansd" ng-controller="ApplicationController as AppCtrl"></html>
But I can document.write("asdasd") to overwrite the page if I enter into console after the page is loaded.
And even I put  document.documentElement.remove(); to remove the whole HTML (yes, removed successfully) after stop() , I still cannot document.write("asdasd").
Is this due to the javascript problem or it's Chrome's problem, or it's my problem? Please help. Thank you very much.

Delaying stop seems to work:
let writeHTML = function (strHTML) {
    setTimeout(stop);
    document.write(strHTML)
}

A more reliable workaround might be to open a tab with url: 'foo.html' where foo.html is a page in your extension, which will then modify itself using data from the background script.

wow, surprisingly it works...
why is that?

Apparently because stop does stop everything once and for all, so it must be postponed.
